# Given a large random number, what is the most gas-efficient way to get a further set of "unpredictable" smaller numbers?

Tags: solidity

I'm using chainlink to get a random number. I need a bunch more random numbers.

I'm currently using:

```
[
  uint256(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(randomNumber, nonce))),
  uint256(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(randomNumber, nonce + 1)))
];
```

But I wonder if there is anything gas-efficient techniques I should consider?

Answer (score 2):

Please see the answer [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/112331/gas-efficient-way-to-generate-multiple-different-random-numbers?rq=1). If you don't need the full whole number (quite likely), it should work for you.

To put it shortly: assuming you actually only need a limit of "a" for the first random number and "b" for the second number, and we'll mark Chainlink random number as `x`: first random number would be x % a, second number x / a % b, third number x / a / b % c, etc'.

To make it more efficient, first of all use bitwise operations instead of plain mod/div, and also use bitwise shift to efficiently reduce the number each iteration (instead of doing x / a / b).